# How to write a char to the stdin in C?

Tags: c, linux, file, process, stdin

I'm making a minishell and I have to create in C a command as "<<" in bash.
So I have to enter some input in the terminal and redirect it to the standard input but I'm having problems doing this.

Example of what should happen:

```
Minishell > cat << deli
> jlaf
> faljs
> deli
jlaf
faljs
```

What is happening:

```
Minishell > cat << deli
> jlaf
> faljs
> deli
jlaf
faljs
```

Is the same but it gets stuck after faljs.
The code for "<<" is the following:

```
buffer = readline("> ");
while (strncmp(buffer, delimiter, ft_strlen(buffer)) != 0)
{
    str = ft_strjoin(str, ft_strjoin("\n", buffer);
    free(buffer);
    buffer = readline("> ");
}
write(0, str+1, ft_strlen(str));
```

readline() is the c function which reads the input of every line till it reaches the delimiter in the loop, ft_strjoin simply joins two strings and returns a new one. At the end I try to write all the lines read to the stdin which I think is the problem. Later I execute a process in execve, for example cat if I have put "cat << delimiter" to the stdout and supposedly with the previously written information in the stdin. But something is wrong and it shows the output but I get stuck in the terminal.
¿What could be the problem in this code?

Comment: Depends on the OS. In unix system (e.g Linux), you need to create a pipe, dup2 that pipe onto fd 0 in the child (i.e. after forking but before exec), and write to that pipe in the parent.

Comment: And this is just one form of redirection.  If you're supporting here documents then presumably you are also supporting redirecting from a file with `<` and to a file with `>`.  Possibly you are also supporting pipelines with `|`.  All of these forms of redirection use similar building blocks, especially the `dup` family of functions, with judicious use of pipes.  I would be looking for ways to share code for these capabilities.

Comment: Normally (traditionally), you'd write the here document to a file (probably an anonymous file) and then duplicate the file descriptor of the file to the child's standard input (and close it in the parent).  Being anonymous, the file data will be released when the last process with a file descriptor for the file exits.  You don't show error checking on the `write(0, …)` — you should.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: i think that's worth making into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring a comment into a semblance of an answer.*</sup>

Normally (traditionally), you'd write the here document to a file (probably an anonymous file) and then duplicate the file descriptor of the file to the child's standard input (and close it in the parent). Being anonymous, the file data will be released when the last process with a file descriptor for the file exits.

An "anonymous" file is a file which you create with a name (and for which you get a file descriptor) and then immediately remove.  The standard C [`tmpfile()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tmpfile.html) creates such a file for you but returns a file stream (`FILE *`).  You probably want the equivalent that gives you a file descriptor.  The POSIX functions [`mkstemp()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) and
[`unlink()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html) would give you that functionality.